# How to read data file?

Tags: batch-file

If I have data `file.txt` and I want to read data from it into variable by using the command :  `set`

How can I do that?
How can I move one line to another?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read two lines from a file, based on your comments:

```
@echo off
setLocal EnableDelayedExpansion

for /f "tokens=* delims= " %%a in (file.txt) do (
set /a N+=1
set v!N!=%%a
)

set sn=!v1!
set s=!v2!
```

You may want to consider using a scripting language, if you want to process multiple lines.

Comment: isn't batch file called scipting language?

Comment: This command reads lines from a file and sets the environment variable var to the last line read. Batch files have some scripting capabilities, but you have to put in a lot of effort to perform non-trivial tasks. A dedicated scripting language such as Perl, Python or Ruby makes this much easier.

Comment: I have a batch file that includes this lines: "set /p sn=<data.txt the next line is the same line with a different variable: set /p s=<data.txt. I want the first line in data.txt file to be inserted to sn variable and the second line to s. is it possible????

Comment: First of all thanx- is this command run till the end of the text?

Comment: I mean till the end of the data file.txt??- sorry, I supposed to do that & i'm not good in it

Answer (score 0):

This will give you line one in the variable:

```
@echo off
set /p var=<file.txt 
echo "%var%"
pause
```